# generate random static final number in java

Tags: java, random, numbers

I'm making a game for my school and I can't do that a static final int gets a random number, the game is asteroids and the asteroids are make with polygons, i can change the points of the polygon with this:

```
private static final int NUMBER_OF_POINTS = 5;
```

and if i put

```
private static final int NUMBER_OF_POINTS = 3;
```

it makes a triangle but i want that when the game start it generate random figures this by generating random numbers in the :

```
private static final int NUMBER_OF_POINTS = 3;
```

here is what i have made, but it doesnt work:

```
private static final int NUMBER_OF_POINTS = 3 + (int)(Math.random() * (5 - 3) + 1));
```

and here is the whole code :

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package game;

import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.util.Random;


public enum AsteroidSize {

    /**
     * Small Asteroids have a radius of 15, and are worth 150 points.
     */
    XtraSmall(5.0, 150),
    /**
     * Small Asteroids have a radius of 15, and are worth 100 points.
     */
    Small(15.0, 100),

    /**
     * Medium asteroids have a radius of 25, and are worth 50 points.
     */
    Medium(25.0, 50),

    /**
     * Large asteroids have a radius of 40, and are worth 20 points.
     */
    Large(40.0, 20),
        /**
     * XtraLarge asteroids have a radius of 40, and are worth 10 points.
     */
        XtraLarge(50.0, 10);

    /**
     * The number of points on the Asteroid.
     */
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_POINTS = 5;

    /**
     * The polygon for this type of Asteroid.
     */
    public final Polygon polygon;

    /**
     * The radius of this type of Asteroid.
     */
    public final double radius;

    /**
     * The number of points earned for killing this type of Asteroid.
     */
    public final int killValue;

    /**
     * Creates a new type of Asteroid.
     * @param radius The radius.
     * @param value The kill value.
     */
    private AsteroidSize(double radius, int value) {
        this.polygon = generatePolygon(radius);
        this.radius = radius + 1.0;
        this.killValue = value;
    }

    /**
     * Generates a regular polygon of size radius.
     * @param radius The radius of the Polygon.
     * @return The generated Polygon.
     */
    private static Polygon generatePolygon(double radius) {
        //Create an array to store the coordinates.
        int[] x = new int[NUMBER_OF_POINTS];
        int[] y = new int[NUMBER_OF_POINTS];

        //Generate the points in the polygon.
        double angle = (2 * Math.PI / NUMBER_OF_POINTS);
        for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_POINTS; i++) {
            x[i] = (int) (radius * Math.sin(i * angle));
            y[i] = (int) (radius * Math.cos(i * angle));
        }

        //Create a new polygon from the generated points and return it.
        return new Polygon(x, y, NUMBER_OF_POINTS);
    }

}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: i expect that the asteroids that are generated had diferent shapes like if i put 3 points i would see a triangle or if i put 4 i would see a rectangle, instead it doesnt show the figures if i start shooting i get the points because of the collisions but the figures just dont appear

Comment: So it doesn't have anything to do with the random static final int? You're asking why figures don't appear on the screen? Well, you didn't post any code related to showing figures on the screen, so it's hard to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this instead

```
Random random = new Random();
int rand;
rand = random.nextInt(8) + 3; // here a number will be generated between 3 and 8, 3 is a triangle 8 octogon so you can change 8 but leave 3 alone.
NUMBER_OF_POINTS = rand; // number of points is now equal to a number between 3 and 8.
```

i have a feeling you cant change the value of a final variable so maybe get rid of final. Let me know if this is along the line of what you were looking for.

Comment: You could also increase the radius by altering the length of each side.

Comment: that work for me, yes final was all the problem and tom i have not think in that